# How can I compile with NetBeans without boot classes?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, netbeans, bootclasspath

I want compile and debug the Java VM self. That I want remove the boot classes from compiling and running. Before I have do this with Eclipse where it is very easy. You need only to remove the Java library from the build path. But Eclipse does not support Java 7 syntax now. That I have switch to NetBeans.

How can I remove the bootclasspath from compiling with NetBeans?

Comment: How did you add it?  There are number of way you could have done this.

Comment: I am very new to NetBeans. I have create a java project from existing sources. The IDE has set my default Java platform to the project automatically.  If I remove java.lang.Object from my project there is no compiler error. This means it use the classes of the Java VM and not only from my project.

Comment: You can only add or remove your library, you cannot remove the whole JRE library without replacing everything. It sounds like you want to know how to ADD your class to the boot class so it will replace the existing classes.  Note: Object is a special class so you have to be careful what changes you make or it will break the JVM.

Comment: @Horcrux7, are you compiling the OpenJDK sources?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds Yes, I want compiling a modified OpenJDK.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I know but want compile the Java part of the VM self for example to replace rt.jar. Then all needed classes must be exists. Also java.lang.Object. This was only a sample to show the problem. My current problem is that I receive no compiler errors if I have forgot a source file. This occur at runtime and this is bad.

Comment: @Horcrux7, having compiled OpenJDK 6 before, I can only point you to the [OpenJDK page on using Netbeans](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/nb-projects/); the page is quite dated, but I think the nbproject files are still available in the sources you would have checked out. I'm afraid my experience with compiling the JDK has been limited to the commandline, so I cannot be of more help.

Comment: @Horcrux7, also you might need to set the `ALT_BOOTDIR` [explicitly](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html#bootjdk); I'm not sure how this will be used in a Netbeans project.

Comment: @Horcrux7, Rather than re-building all the classes, you should just rebuild the classes you change. Add these to the boot class path and it will work. I am not sure what situation you are trying to protect yourself from.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey this will work only for simple changes. But I need to replace many classes. Some packages are completely rewritten.

Comment: @Horcrux7, The JDK contains 7000 classes developed over a period of 15+ years. If you alone plan to redevelop a significant portion of these classes I suggest you reconsider because by the time you have finished they will been changed in Java 8+. Perhaps you should start with a small portion of say a few 100 classes first.  You can't change the API significantly or any code which has been compiled against the existing API won't work. Of course we are speaking hypothetically as changing core libraries breaks the license agreement. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey The changes was already write for years. We migrate now to Java 7 from Java 6. And I not the own people that work on it. It is the IKVM project. And we hope that the changes between Java 7 and 8 will not so large like between 6 and 7.

Comment: @Horcrux7, My understanding is that Java 8 has all the changes that were too hard to get into Java 7.  I imagine the differences will be greater e.g. Closures.